# Overlaying a background image to an activity

Tags: android, android-view

I have an activity with a background. When I lose internet connectivity I'd like to overlay another image on the top of my existing background (50% opaque).

Is there an easy way to do this without having to go through the draw method of the main view of my activity?

Thanks.

Comment: Include an ImageView in you main layout and set it to INVISIBLE.  Set it's background to the icon you want and in your code, set it to VISIBLE when you need to show it.

Comment: @quinestor To be fair, he does have 12 questions and 0 answers.

Comment: @quinestor I was referring to I_ingenu's previous questions. I see how you could misread my comment as "gimme points now", but I don't tend to refer to myself as "them" and understand that a question cannot be accept in the first 15 minutes. Next time I'll add the phrase "going back and" to my reminder to thank the people that help you.

Comment: @Sam I am not sure I am got your comment. What do you expect me to?

Comment: @Simon I am afraid this does not address my problem. I am looking to fill the entire background with an opaque (c. 50%) image. If I place an ImageView, it will just be another widget like the others on my screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can control any View's alpha channel (opacity) with [`setAlpha()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29).

Try:

```
imageView.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Comment: Yup, although sadly that wasn't implemented until API 11 (Android 4.0). :( You may be better off including a separate PNG at 50% opacity and using that, if you need to support older OS versions.

Comment: Keeping with @Sam - [AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html) may be a good compromise for API Levels < 11.